# Failed while running glusterfs rpm

Tags: rpm, glusterfs

I am trying to run rpm of glusterfs. I ran the following command;

```
rpm -Uvh glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64.rpm
```

It gives the following errors;

```
Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/bash is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    glusterfs-libs = 4.1.2-3.fc29 is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.3)(64bit) is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
    systemd is needed by glusterfs-4.1.2-3.fc29.x86_64
```

Does it need dependencies or are there any problem in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs dependencies, basically a later version of glibc.

Try rebuilding the glusterfs SRPM against your glibc next.